# Jquery hide div partially

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to adjust the width of the div using jquery on click event, and i can't seem to figure out what the exact syntax is.

below is an example of what i tried so far.

```
$(function() {
    $("#square").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).css("width", "50")){
            $(this).animate({width:"500"}, 1000);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({width:"50"}, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4GGP8/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to include jquery library in your jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4GGP8/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your if statement try `$(this).width() == 50` instead, since first of all `css();` functions retrieves the unit as well and second of all you're not making a comparison in the if statement like that, if anything you should do `$(this).css('width') == "50px"` to retrieve the width and compare it.

For future reference you can always use `parseInt();` to get rid of the unit added by css
so doing this is also valid

```
if(parseInt($(this).css('width')) == "50")
```

**The code:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#square").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).width() == 50){
            $(this).animate({width:"500"}, 1000);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({width:"50"}, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

*Here is the resulting* [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GGP8/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/4GGP8/7/)

```
    $("#square").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).css('width') == '50px'){
            $(this).animate({width:"500"}, 1000);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({width:"50"}, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you looked at this line in my code - `if($(this).css('width') == '50px'){`